# StackLayout within ScrollView, wrong control focus UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, scrollview, stacklayout

I have following ContentPage

```
<ContentPage>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Editor Text="description" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="10" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Whem I am running this under UWP there is strange behavior: If I scroll down a bit and try to hit e.g. 6th Editor, I get focus on 3rd Editor control.
When I am on the top of scroll viewer I get focus to correct Editor but If I scroll a bit I get wrong Editor focused.
 It looks like I can reach only first X Editors visible on the top of ScrollView.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using Xamarin.Forms. This is bug in framework for UWP platform.

You can find this issue in https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11106.

Please upgrade framework to 4.7.0.1080. This works for me.